# Dimension swap from cube to matrix in rcpp

Tags: multidimensional-array, rcpp, dimensions

I encountered an interesting problem today. In one of my postprocessing functions of my code, I do some where I have 3dimensional cubes out of an MCMC algorithm. When accessing the cube, I assumed that anything I extract will result in a Matris, as I also tried to save it. Nevertheless, if one of the dimensions is just 1 weird stuff happens. I'll give you a small example:

```
library(Rcpp)
library(RcppArmadillo)

cppFunction("arma::mat test(arma::cube Rarray) {
arma::mat test = Rarray.row(0);
return test;
}", depends="RcppArmadillo")

Rarray1 <- array(NA, dim=c(100,1,2))
Rarray2 <- array(NA, dim=c(100,2,1))
```

When letting run the function and looking at the dimensions, I get

```
dim(test(Rarray1))
> 1 2
dim(test(Rarray2))
> 1 2
```

So extracting the first row of the array/cube and saving it in a matrix swaps the dimensions. My guess is that internally Rcpp takes out the first row of Rarray, which is a 1x2 or 2x1 matrix. Regardless of that, whenever one of dimensions is just one it transforms it to a column vector (the default in Armadillo) and then saves it to the matrix. Therefore, I always will get back a column vector saved in a matrix, which results in a 1x2 matrix. But that's just a guess.

Is there any way to prevent this behavior? Similar to `drop=FALSE`in R.

Comment: It is possible that we have a garden variety bug there.  `Cube` types are used less often.  Can you take a stick a poke around in the converters?  That's all code in RcppArmadillo in the inst/include/ directory and is "independent" of Rcpp in the sense that the RcppArmadillo package does the conversion for Armadillo types.

Comment: What exactly should I do there?

Comment: It's depends on how at ease you are with (gnarly) C++.  "That is where it happens" so you suspect foul play you could try some debugging there.  Otherwise, "avoid it" but using Armadillo itself to take whatever slices or portions you want from the Cube and get those back to R as matrix objects. Those are very well tested.

Comment: I am not realy that much into C++, I am merely using it for outsourcing code from R to gain computational speed. Furthermore, I use this kind of code snippet in a package and I have created a workaround with an if-query now, so at the moment it works (with a few extra lines of code). But I thought maybe it's worth noting it, since it is kind of not-intuitive behavior for me.

Comment: That's ok. You can still help, for example with a detailed enough (reproducible) but report.  We have another on Fields over at the GH repo: https://github.com/RcppCore/RcppArmadillo/issues/263  Maybe you can add something?

Comment: Sure, I can do that. Should I just open a new issue?

Comment: Yes please.  As it is a 'new' bug.